# Debugging form submission

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome

Trying to debug form submission and console shows error for split second, failing at catching it with a print screen

Is there a way to keep the error message there on page reload in chrome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the `Preserve log upon navigation` checkbox in the settings